# Magento 404 page not found

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404

I made a new store view for my language and disabled all other store views, I made page called Kodu and set it as default home page under Configuration - Web.

Now when I clear my cookies I get `404 error: Page not found` unless I use a direct link to go to CMS page "Kodu" _store=eesti">http://mypage.ee/live/index.php/kodu/?_store=eesti after I load that page and go back to mypage.ee/live it loads the right home page.

What should I do to get rid of this error ?

Comment: What is the URI that it tries to load when you get the 404? Does it still have the URI arguments? `?store=eesti`

Comment: It loads http://mypage.ee/live/ when I get 404 error. After I've loaded http://mypage.ee/live/index.php/kodu/?_store=eesti once and go back to load http://mypage.ee/live/ it loads http://mypage.ee/live/index.php/.

Comment: Well, it's not loading the alternate store. I haven't worked in a multi-store environment, hopefully someone more knowledgeable in that area could help you. Have you completely cleared out and refreshed your cache, reindex, etc?

Comment: Cleared cache, reindexed. Well I just have one store and want to have just one store view with my language, I made new store view of my language called Eesti, disabled English, French and German store views, could that be making trouble?

Comment: Alright I enabled English store view again and now it loads the home page correctly, but in English store view. I'd like it to load mine as default. I'm not expecting English costumers so currently I just need it in Estonian.

Answer (score -1):

Solution was actually pretty easy, I just had to go to Manage Stores under Configurations and click on the store to edit not the store view. There I set default store view to Eesti and that got rid of the 404 error and I could keep English store view disabled.